# Question about a consequence of the Rank-Nullity Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Well, I have been thinking of this for quite a bit now. If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $F$ and $f$ is a linear transformation $V \to W$, the Rank-Nullity Theorem states that the dimension of finite dimensional vector space $V$ is given by
$$\textbf{dim} V = \textbf{rank} f + \textbf{nullity} f$$.

My question is suppose that $f$ is just a transformation of $V$ to $V$ itself, and that the intersection of the kernel and the image of $f$ is just the trivial space (the space that contains only the zero vector), then wouldn't that imply that:

$V=\textbf{ker} f \oplus \textbf{Im} f$?

Comment: What is your definition of a transformation?  Just a map of sets?

Comment: A linear transformation

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  If $W_1,W_2$ are two subspaces of a vector space $V$ which intersect only at the trivial vector, then $V=W_1\oplus W_2$.

Comment: This is true. An interesting fact is that this property always holds for projection maps, or, more generally, idempotent maps.

Comment: What do you mean "generally"? If this is true for any vector space, then why the need to point out specific maps wherein this is true?

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I just do not get what you are saying

Comment: @freeRmodule: under the condition $\dim W_1+\dim W_2=\dim V$.

Comment: Ah, good point.  Thanks.

Comment: @SumRay This is true for any vector space and for any map where the intersection of the kernel and image is $0$. I was providing a few examples of properties linear maps could have that imply this intersection is $0$, because I find it interesting, and it was useful in my study, and it is not true for every map. It often isn't easy to directly check what that intersection is, but checking if a map is idempotent is usually very easy. The "generally" refers to "idempotent" as a generalization of projection maps.